# Exception while running spring integration with zookeeper

Tags: spring-integration, apache-zookeeper, spring-integration-sftp

when i am running spring integration SFTP with zookeeper: Facing issue while file metada put in metadatastore. i have mention below code.
Below is my configuration

```
<beans:bean id="compositeFilter"
        class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.ChainFileListFilter">

        <beans:constructor-arg >
        <beans:set>
          <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter">
                        <beans:constructor-arg value="^.*\.(dat|DAT)$" />
                </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="store"
                        ref="metadataStore" />
                    <beans:constructor-arg value="filterprefix" />
                </beans:bean>
          </beans:set>

        </beans:constructor-arg>

    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="zookeeperClient"
        class="org.springframework.integration.zookeeper.config.CuratorFrameworkFactoryBean">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="${zookeeper.server.uri}" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="metadataStore"
        class="org.springframework.integration.zookeeper.metadata.ZookeeperMetadataStore">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="zookeeperClient" />
        <beans:property name="root" value="/metaDataStore" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Below are the exception trace which I am getting. when i run above program i am getting following error.

```
Caused by: 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path string "/AtdFaureciaMetaDataStore/.." caused by relative paths not allowed @27
    at org.apache.curator.utils.PathUtils.validatePath(PathUtils.java:102)
    at org.apache.curator.utils.PathUtils.validatePath(PathUtils.java:37)
    at org.apache.curator.utils.ZKPaths.fixForNamespace(ZKPaths.java:105)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceImpl.fixForNamespace(NamespaceImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.fixForNamespace(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:599)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:458)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:44)
    at org.springframework.integration.zookeeper.metadata.ZookeeperMetadataStore.createNode(ZookeeperMetadataStore.java:257)
    at org.springframework.integration.zookeeper.metadata.ZookeeperMetadataStore.putIfAbsent(ZookeeperMetadataStore.java:119)
```

Comment: There should be more StackTrace. Please, share that bottom from the target `CuratorFramework`

Comment: i have mention the stack trace now. please refer

Comment: at FTP server location, i guess when i am putting the file, at top it is seeing .. and then file listing. because of this may be it is giving me error

Comment: Please, consider to format code and stack trace properly. Now it isn’t readable

Comment: i have modified the stack trace. please refer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to use `ChainFileListFilter` instead of `CompositeFileListFilter`:

```
**
 * The {@link CompositeFileListFilter} extension which chains the result
 * of the previous filter to the next one. If a filter in the chain returns
 * an empty list, the remaining filters are not invoked.
 *
 * @param <F> The type that will be filtered.
 *
 * @author Artem Bilan
 * @author Gary Russell
 *
 * @since 4.3.7
 *
 */
public class ChainFileListFilter<F> extends CompositeFileListFilter<F> {
```

It doesn’t pass discarded files to the next filters in chain.

On the other hand really consider some non-empty `prefix` for the `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` to avoid that relative path error.

Comment: it is giving me following error : Error creating bean with name 'compositeFilter' defined in URL [ftpIntegrationConfig.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Comment: Please, use an edit function for the question to demonstrate big piece of code: it’s not readable on comments. More over we don’t have the code in that your comment at all!

Comment: i have edited configuration code and stack trace in question which i am getting. please refer

Comment: Do we have an actual bean definition for the `compositeFilter` in your question?

Comment: i have changed the bean name and question as well which is having full code

Comment: You have a mess in your code here in the question. I see there two `compositeFilter`

Comment: FYI: `ChainFileListFiter` doesn’t have constructor. See it’s JavaDocs and source code. You have to use setter to inject delegates

Comment: how can i use ChainFileListFilter using xml ?

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. We don’t expose the property to set external filters by the xml config convention. You have to extend the `ChainFileListFilter` and add setter to call `addFilters()`. Please, raise a JIRA on the matter and we’ll add one more ctor into it

Comment: thank you for this. but now  i am getting org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available exception. i have updated the question

Comment: Well, you know: that is already a new question not related to the original one. In SO rules it would be better to start a new thread on the matter do not confuse readers. You have that exception because your flow is one-way and you don’t have `outputChannel` on the service-activator in the end. If you are not interested in the reply from there, you can use `nullChannel` on the matter

Comment: I have updated the question to the question which i was getting earlier. and my error is also get resolved. Thanks